# Margin % Bridge - Effect of Price, Cost, Volume

Tags: margin

Given sales and profitability data for two time periods, how would I go about calculating the impact of price, cost, volume and mix margin % (bps)? I can do the analysis as a gross margin $ bridge, but I'm unable to convert that to margin %.

I'd like to create something like this: http://www.pwc.com/en_GX/gx/technology/publications/assets/technology-news-gross-margin-analysis.pdf

Looking at that analysis, I can't reconcile how $2.5M in price be favorable 120 bps to margin.

Std Margin of \$174.2m (57.2%) 
Price of \$2.5m (1.2%)

Would suggest that margin after the price change is 58.4%

Working backwards
Std Margin of $174.2 at 57.2% would mean:

Revenue: \$304.54m (174.2 / .572)
Cost: $130.34m

A $2.5m price increase would be 174.2+2.5 = 176.7m of margin on 304.54+2.5 = 307.04m revenue, which is only 57.5% margin or 30 bps difference. How does 120 bps get derived?

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this? if so, could you provide me with some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough data. You could only derive 2 variables without knowing more details.
Here is the formula for 2 variables:

[image]